# Custom Kaleo workflow for Page deletion

Tags: liferay-7

i am trying to implement Custom workflow for Page deletion. I have created Kaleo workflow defination, enabled staging configuration details and configured workflow details in site level. created a listener and overridden /layout/delete_layout action and implemented  doProcessAction() method and called startWorkflowInstance() to start workflow as given below.

```
  @Override
    protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

        _log.info("CustomDeleteLayoutMVCActionCommand doProcessAction() ");
        /*----------------*/
         long plid = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "selPlid");
         Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.fetchLayout(plid);
         LayoutRevision layoutRevision = _layoutStaging.getLayoutRevision(layout);

         ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
          long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
          long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
          long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
          User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
          String transitionName = "Reviewer";
          _log.info("CustomDeleteLayoutMVCActionCommand doProcessAction() userId:: "+userId+" companyId::"+companyId+" groupId::"+groupId);
          String className = "com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.LayoutRevision";
          long classPK = layoutRevision.getLayoutRevisionId();
          _log.info("  classPK::"+classPK);
          Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext = new HashMap<>();
          WorkflowHandler<User> workflowHandler = WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.getWorkflowHandler(className);
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_SERVICE_CONTEXT, ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest));
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID, String.valueOf(companyId));
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_GROUP_ID, String.valueOf(groupId));
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_NAME, className);
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK, String.valueOf(classPK));
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_TYPE, workflowHandler.getType(LocaleUtil.getDefault()));
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_TRANSITION_NAME, transitionName);
          workflowContext.put(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_NAME, "com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.LayoutRevision");

          long[] categoryIds = new long[10];
          String[] assetTagNames = actionRequest.getParameterValues("assetTagNames");
          AssetEntry assetEntry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(userId,groupId, new Date(), new Date(), LayoutRevision.class.getName(),
                  layoutRevision.getLayoutRevisionId(), "",layoutRevision.getLayoutRevisionId(), categoryIds,assetTagNames, true, 
                  false, new Date(), new Date(),new Date(), new Date(), ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML, layoutRevision.getName(), layoutRevision.getName(), 
                  "", "", "", 0, 0, 00.00);

          Indexer<LayoutRevision> indexer = IndexerRegistryUtil.nullSafeGetIndexer(LayoutRevision.class);
          indexer.reindex(layoutRevision);

          try {

            WorkflowDefinition latestWorkflowDefinition = WorkflowDefinitionManagerUtil.getLatestWorkflowDefinition(companyId, "Reviewer-Checker Approval Workflow"); 
            _log.info(latestWorkflowDefinition.getName());
              /*try {
                  WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil.startWorkflowInstance( 
                          companyId,
                          groupId,
                          userId,
                          latestWorkflowDefinition.getName(),
                          latestWorkflowDefinition.getVersion(),
                          transitionName,
                          workflowContext
                  );
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  _log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
              }*/
              try {
                  WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance( 
                          companyId,
                          groupId,
                          userId,
                          className,
                          layoutRevision.getLayoutRevisionId(),
                          layoutRevision,
                          ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest),
                          workflowContext
                  );
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  _log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
              }
              /*LayoutWorkflowHandler layoutWorkflowHandler = new LayoutWorkflowHandler();
              layoutWorkflowHandler.updateStatus(1, workflowContext);*/
          } catch (WorkflowException e) {
              _log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
          }
          _log.info("CustomDeleteLayoutMVCActionCommand doProcessAction() started ");
    @Reference
    private LayoutStaging _layoutStaging;



@Component(
        property = {"model.class.name=com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Layout"},
        service = WorkflowHandler.class
    )
LayoutWorkflowHandler.java
public class LayoutWorkflowHandler extends BaseWorkflowHandler<LayoutRevision>{

    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(LayoutWorkflowHandler.class.getName());
    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return LayoutRevision.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Locale locale) {
        return ResourceActionsUtil.getModelResource(locale, getClassName());
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutRevision updateStatus(int status, Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext) throws PortalException {
        _log.info("LayoutWorkflowHandler updateStatus()");
        long userId = GetterUtil.getLong(
            (String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID));
        long layoutRevisionId = GetterUtil.getLong( (String)workflowContext.get(
                WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext)workflowContext.get("serviceContext");
         _log.info("layoutRevisionId::"+layoutRevisionId);
       /* DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(LayoutRevision.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
        dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("entryClassPK", classPK));
        dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("groupId", workflowContext.get("groupId")));

        _log.info("LayoutWorkflowHandler updateStatus() classPK ::"+classPK+" groupId:: "+workflowContext.get("groupId")); 
        List<LayoutRevision> layoutRevisionsList = LayoutRevisionLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
        _log.info("LayoutWorkflowHandler updateStatus() layoutRevisionsList size ::"+layoutRevisionsList.size()); 
        long layoutRevisionId = 0;
        for(LayoutRevision layoutRevision : layoutRevisionsList) {
            layoutRevisionId = layoutRevision.getLayoutRevisionId();
            _log.info("LayoutWorkflowHandler updateStatus() layoutRevisionId:: "+layoutRevisionId); 
        }*/
        return _LayoutRevisionLocalService.updateStatus(userId, layoutRevisionId, status, serviceContext);

    }
    @Reference
    private LayoutRevisionLocalService _LayoutRevisionLocalService;
}
```

But I am not getting Notification when I login with reviewer/checker role to approve page and page is getting deleting without any approval.

Kindly kelp me if I am doing anything wrong and Please share me if some samples or Steps. Thank you very much

Regards,
Madhava